# I cant get into the agenda buffer

Tags: org-mode

How do I get into the agenda buffer?

I tried `C-c a`, but it doesn't work; nothing happens.

Comment: are you trying the key binding while in org buffer, otherwise add `(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)` to your .emacs

Answer (score 1):

**SOLUTION**

According to the org manual you need to define `C-c a` globally.

In your `.emacs` or `init.el` file add the following line:

```
(global-set-key "\C-ca" 'org-agenda)
```

This should trigger the agenda buffer; I hope this helps someone.

**REFERENCES**

https://orgmode.org/manual/Activation.html#Activation

Comment: This is part of the (documented) [setup](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Activation).

Comment: NickD - you are right.